# No origin mentioned in git status, but pushing and fetching work

Tags: git, repository

I have local git repository and one remote repository on gitlab.com. As opposite to another similar situation, the command `git status` print out nothing about origin.

The output of `git status -uno` (there are many untracked files, so I skip them)

```
On branch master
nothing to commit (use -u to show untracked files)
```

where us elsewhere it is

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

Do you know how to get the expected behavior (the second one)?

I suspect it can be the result of set the origin twice. During the initialization, I did

```
$ git push --set-upstream https://gitlab.com/<username>/projectA.git
$ git push --set-upstream https://gitlab.com/<username>/projectB.git
$ git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/<username>/projectB.git
```

I removed origin and set it again:

```
$ git remote rm origin
$ git push --set-upstream https://gitlab.com/<username>/projectB.git
$ git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/<username>/projectB.git
```

I tested how origin looks like via `git remote -v`. It shows me nothing after removing the origin, in every other moment the result was (and is now):

```
origin  https://gitlab.com/<username>/projectB.git (fetch)
origin  https://gitlab.com/<username>/projectB.git (push)
```

`git fetch` behaves in other way I know. It returns

```
$ git fetch -v
POST git-upload-pack (102 bytes)
From https://gitlab.com/<username>/projectB
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

For standard situation I get

```
$ git fetch -v
POST git-upload-pack (155 bytes)
From https://gitlab.com/<username>/projectC
 = [up to date]      main       -> origin/main
```

For completness, I did `git gc` and `git prune` in some moment. This is something what I did first time, so I have no experience if it has some side-effects related to this problem.

Comment: Did you `git push` after re-setting the remote `origin`? Do you see `origin/master` if you `git log`?

Comment: I tried `git push` and `git log` but likely in bad moment, when all is aligned (up to date). Meanwhile, I solved my problem via the answer @LeGEC. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To "fix" your issue:*

once you have defined a named remote (in your question: `origin`), and fetched its branches, you can :

```
git branch -u origin/main
```

---

You need to use named remotes in order to keep a remote tracking branch. When you use explicit urls, `git` will not store the branches it fetches locally (or the branch you update by running `git push`), so you find yourself with nothing to point to, even when specifying `--set-upstream`.

If you routinely need to push or pull from two different remotes, give them different names :

```
# for example :
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/<username>/projectB.git
git remote add upstream https://gitlab.com/<username>/projectA.git
```

Comment: Your answer solved my problem, thanks. Slowly learning git :)